# Drools Can't bind a list to a variable

Tags: java, drools

I have a function which returns a list. I am trying to call this function in drools when clause and binding it to a variable called l1. If I bind the variable like this, then clause doesn't execute. However, if I bind the map in a similar way statements in then clause executes.
I am using the latest version of drools.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

dialect "java"

function Map<Integer, Integer> f1(){
  Map<Integer, Integer> h = new HashMap<>();
  h.put(1,2);
  h.put(2,6);
  return h;
}

function List<Integer> f2(){
  List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
  l.add(1);
  l.add(2);
  return l;
}

rule "test1"
when
    $m1: Map() from f1()
then
    System.out.println("Inside test1");
    System.out.println($m1);
end

rule "test2"
when
    $l1: List() from f2()
then
    System.out.println("Inside test2");
    System.out.println($l1);
end
```

Here rule 'test1' executes and prints the values. But I don't see any output from rule 'test2'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see is caused by the special treatment `Iterables` receive by the `from` operator in Drools.

In Drools, you can use the `from` operator to actually iterate over an `Iterable` and to apply the left pattern to each of its elements. So for example, you can do
something like this:

```
function List<String> getNames(){
  List<String> n = new ArrayList<>();
  n.add("John Doe");
  n.add("Peter Seller");
  n.add("John Wick");
  return n;
} 

rule "Filter Johns"
when
    $j: String(this matches "John.*") from getNames()
then
    System.out.println("John found: "+$j);
end
```

The "Filter Johns" rule will execute the `getNames()` function and it will apply the `String(this matches "John.*")` pattern to each of the elements in the `List` returned by the function. For this particulat case, the rule will be activated twice.

In you example, because the `Map` is not an `Iterable`, then the `from` applies the left pattern to it without iterating. In your second rule, the `fc2()` function gets executed, the `from` retrieves a `List` with 2 `Integers` and it applies the pattern `List()` to each of them. Of course, this will not cause any activation.

A clear way to see this behavior in you case would be to modify your second rule like this:

```
rule "test2"
when
    $l1: Object() from f2()
then
    System.out.println("Inside test2");
    System.out.println($l1);
end
```

In this case, you will see that the rule gets executed twice.

Comment: Nice explanation.